# Where is the subject? "and injured his left arm severely"

Tags: parts-of-speech, subjects

> A clause is the smallest unit of English grammar and it is made up of a **subject and a verb**. To have clauses, we need phrases and with the combination of two or more clauses we get sentences. [Grammar Bank](http://www.grammarbank.com/clause-phrase-sentence.html)

in the same page there is an example:

> A famous celebrity had an unfortunate accident a long time ago (first clause)
>   when he didn't use his safety equipment (second clause) and injured his left arm severely. (third clause)

**Where is the subject in the third clause?**

Comment: Grammar Bank is wrong on just about everything, e.g. a sentence can be a single clause, for example "I am a student" has just one clause - it's a clausal sentence. The example you give has a coordination of two verb phrases functioning as predicate of the subject "he": "... he [didn't use his safety equipment] and [injured his left arm severely]. Note that the bracketed elements are not clauses but VPs (verb phrases), contrary to what Grammar Bank says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject is omitted as well as the subordinate conjunction **when**. Consequently, in your example, the sentence reads:

> A famous celebrity had an unfortunate accident a long time ago when he didn't use his safety equipment and **when he** injured his left arm severely.